# USB3.0 Type A socket plastic insert

Tags: usb

This question will probably be downvoted pretty quickly because it sounds like a shopping question, so let me start off by saying I am not looking for the lowest price, or even where to purchase this component. I would simply like to know if a manufacturer exists, and if not, what are my alternatives.

---

A project I am working on requires a slimline **USB3.0 Type A socket** with a height not in excess of 5mm. Standard USB sockets are about 5.7mm tall so I am looking to source the plastic insert of the socket and will fabricate the shielding myself as part of the device's enclosure.

[image: USB3.0 Type A Plug]
<sub>(source: [digikey.com](http://media.digikey.com/Photos/Assmann%20Photos/A-USBPA-3-R.jpg))</sub>

Something similar to this but in a female version (just the blue part with the contacts)

I have searched Mouser, DigiKey, Element14, and Alibaba with no results.

---

I have considered using the PCB itself to form the contacts as I am aware this has been done successfully for Type A **plugs** (fig. 2), however for the **socket** I will need to source the 4 spring contacts used by the original USB standard (VBUS, D-, D+, and GND).

The contacts for StdA_SSRX-, StdA_SSRX+, GND_DRAIN, StdA_SSTX-, and StdA_SSTX+ could simply be pads on the PCB.
[USB2.0 Type A PCB Contacts http://www.theledart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/TPP_5890.jpg](http://www.theledart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/TPP_5890.jpg)

---

I can also use an existing USB3.0 Type A socket and peel away the metal shielding to leave only the plastic insert with the contacts, but if possible I would like to avoid this.

Comment: Would a micro/mini B socket and a gender changer in the cable be an acceptable alternative?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.
The device must act as a USB3.0 host and accept full size type A plugs.

Comment: The blue part in the image appears to be oriented backwards with regard to both of the shields in the image. That's poor marketing, there.

Comment: If your volume is high enough, perhaps the vendors would entertain your need.

Comment: @kenny I doubt I will ever enter mass production with this project. At most I might sell it as a kit. I will keep this option in mind and see if the manufacturer has some spares.

Comment: I've had factories do custom runs before of something they already had a design for in ~1k quantity, which may be an option if you do sell a kit. Just make sure the sales rep on Alibaba or whatever can show you a picture of an actual physical product before going forward.

Comment: Best bet would be either getting regular female connectors and modifying it yourself, or finding a manufacturer of a socket you can use, and see if you can get the component part by itself. They wouldn't have to change anything, just not built it all to completion, so it works out for them.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have problems finding this online simply because (as I've noticed) they tend to be mislabeled.  See [Here](http://www.weiku.com/products/9418592/USB_Type_A_4Pin_Male_Panel_Mount_DIP_Connector.html) is a board mount unit c/w shroud that is a board mount but is labeled as a panel mount.

That link may not be that handy as it has 2K minimum order quantity but it does exist.

I think that your request for the plastic part only won't work because the shroud is needed for the spring contacts to act against.  i.e. the back side of the USB mating unit needs to press against the shroud for the pins to make contact.  But then it could just be your picture not showing that.

[image]

[here](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/USB-Type-A-4Pin-DIP-Male-Panel-Mount-Connector-HW-UAM-05/630060322.html) that part is at 3.79 a lot (100 pieces per lot)

[and the mating part](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/A-TYPE-FEMALE-USB-CONNECTOR-90-DEGREE-RIGHT-ANGLE/582165159.html)

[image]

Comment: OP needs female usb A, not male.

Comment: There seem to be plenty of these unassembled ones available for **male** USB connectors, but no **female** ones.

Answer (score 0):

For prototyping purposes I will continue with readily available USB 3.0 type A sockets and remove the shielding manually. There are 2 small tabs (about 1mm square) that lock the shield onto the plastic. They are a bit difficult to get a tool underneath them to lever them up, but once this is done, the plastic simply slides out towards the rear.

[image: USB 3.0A Female assembly]
The assembled female socket

[image: USB 3.0A Female separated]
Separated, shown upside down

And yes, it still fits snugly without the shielding :)

[image: USB socket without shielding]

Of course the device won't be unshielded - I plan on manufacturing my own shielding for the USB socket as part of the device's shielding, which should allow me to maintain my 5mm maximum height.